# File not found error when creating a private key using CERTENROLLLib

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008, x509certificate, certenroll

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: CertEnroll::CX509PrivateKey::Create:
>   The system cannot find the file specified. 0x80070002 (WIN32: 2)

The error above is the exception thrown when I attempt to create a private key to generate a CSR using the CX509PrivateKeyClass class from CertEnroll.dll.

It only seems to happen when I attempt to execute code deployed on a windows 2008 server.

It runs fine under windows 7.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am having the exact same problem...

Comment: Related posts - For on-premise deployement : [CryptographicException was unhandled: System cannot find the specified file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17840825/465053). For Azure deployment : [Certenroll on Azure - Generating self signed certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58800004/465053)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you don't have proper permission to call the COM. I'm not sure the lowest permission but local administrator should work.