# Unable to generate a CX509PrivateKey when impersonating not logged on user

Tags: c#, impersonation, certenroll

I am using a classic `advapi32` based ImpersonateValidUser code.

I use the user's credentials to submit a request to the CA using CertEnrollLib.
I initiate the request from the private key by building a `CX509PrivateKey`.

If the user has the profile (the user's folder under C:\users) then this code works fine; if the user does not have a profile, the code fails with

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: CertEnroll::CX509PrivateKey::Create: The system  cannot find the file specified. 0x80070002 (WIN32: 2)
```

I looked into loading user profile but it seems to fail for me 'invalid handle' errors.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Related posts - For on-premise deployement : [CryptographicException was unhandled: System cannot find the specified file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17840825/465053). For Azure deployment : [Certenroll on Azure - Generating self signed certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58800004/465053)

Comment: It's amazing that you replied to this old question :) unfortunately this was specifically and only happening where user was impersonated, so IIS workarounds did not work and this was an on-prem windows deployment.

Comment: And the azure question you linked is basically the same as IIS - tell the system to load user profile.