# Cybersource Simple Order Api. The system cannot find the file specified Error Message

Tags: c#, payment-gateway

I have a .Net website (not a Web Application) project running in framework version 4.6.2

My implementation of the Cybersource simple order api works correctly on the development machine.  However when i deploy my website to stage or product i receive the error The system cannot find the file specified when attempting the following code below.

```
NVPClient.RunTransaction(_cyberSourceConfig, request);
```

I have checked that the keys are valid.  The _cyberSourceConfig contains the correct Currency, MerchantId, KeyFile, Key Directory and the locations are valid within the file system.

Check that the following DLL's are included within the projects bin directory

I have also checked that the following DLL's are in my projects bin directory.

```
CyberSource.Base.dll
CyberSource.Clients.dll
CyberSource.Clients.xml
```

_cyberSourceConfig consists of the the following

```
private CyberSource.Clients.Configuration _cyberSourceConfig = new CyberSource.Clients.Configuration();
_cyberSourceConfig.ConnectionLimit = -1;
_cyberSourceConfig.KeyFilename = "setting for key file"
_cyberSourceConfig.KeysDirectory = "path to keys directory"
_cyberSourceConfig.MerchantID = "My merchant id"
_cyberSourceConfig.SendToProduction = false;
_cyberSourceConfig.ServerURL = "https://ics2wstesta.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/";
```

Comment: You have to provide more information. For example what is `_cyberSourceConfig`?

Comment: @svek updated the post as requested

Comment: Did you verify that your `KeyFilename` and `KeysDirectory` are actually resolving properly? You should provide the stack trace results, I'll bet you it's going to point to this issue further down (ie. `System.IO`)

Comment: I send the keys etc to a log file before the below line is executed NVPClient.RunTransaction(_cyberSourceConfig, request);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your App Pool to Load User Profile: True

<strike>http://www.daves-blog.net/post/2014/06/16/X509Certificate-The-System-cannot-find-the-file-specified.aspx</strike>

That link is going to a 404 now, but the more general answer is fleshed out in this question.

[CryptographicException was unhandled: System cannot find the specified file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840825/cryptographicexception-was-unhandled-system-cannot-find-the-specified-file)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your provided information, I would suspect that you are specifying a file that is resolvable on your development machine, but is not resolving properly on your staging / production server.

```
_cyberSourceConfig.KeyFilename = @"keys.foo";
_cyberSourceConfig.KeysDirectory = @"C:\KeysDirectory\MyKeys\"; // <-- are you sure?
```

> You need to make sure that either the relative or absolute paths are the same or are resolving to the file properly when using different enviornments.

Comment: 150% that is not the case.  2 People have checked the file path.  I have also checked the permissions on the folder and Given everyone full control on the directory just encase.