# Read embedded file from resource in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

After publish my site to iis, i get a error as:

> Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException:
>   The system cannot find the file specified

My code to read X509Certificate2 from embedded file is:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = null;
using (var certStream = typeof(T).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
{
    using (var memory = new MemoryStream((int)certStream.Length))
    {
        certStream.CopyTo(memory);
        certificate = new X509Certificate2(memory.ToArray(), password);
    }
}
```

this error only occurred in windows server IIS, but if run Kestrel directly and in IIS Express no problem find.

[image: Break point on stream]

It seams the file is read as unmanaged memory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, adding X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet did the trick.

```
certificate = new X509Certificate2(memory.ToArray(), password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

Found the solution here:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/27358#issuecomment-385433985 ,

http://web.archive.org/web/20151101033040/http://blog.tylerdoerksen.com:80/2013/08/23/pfx-certificate-files-and-windows-azure-websites/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48234395/3080858