# HTTP Error 500.30 (Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified.)

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I am trying to deploy the asp.net core Web API to the IIS. This application works perfectly fine on the Visual studio and also when I run the dll using the dotnet command. This application has the certificate for signing the JWT token. After deploying the application to IIS I am getting "HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure" and I checked the windows log and error message is

Host terminated unexpectedly.
Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified.at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FilterPFXStore(Byte[] rawData, SafePasswordHandle password, PfxCertStoreFlags pfxCertStoreFlags)......

I checked the file path and file name everything is correct but some reason IIS is not able to load find the certificate file. Also, I checked the permission and it also looks good. Not sure why I am getting this error message

Also, I ran the same application dll file using the dotnet run command where IIS is pointing to but I am not getting any error. I am getting this error only after deployng to IIS.

On startup.cs file and configuration method I am getting error on this line.

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2("test_cert.pfx", pwdFrmVault);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I after searching for this error and googling, this solution worked for me. IIS Manager->application pool -> advanced settings ->Under Process model,  Load User Profile to true. More detail on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840825/cryptographicexception-was-unhandled-system-cannot-find-the-specified-file)

Comment: Its so appreciated if you could accept your solution as answer.