# Issue using certificate with .CRT

Tags: x509certificate2

We are having an issue while we use the certificate with .CRT extension - *The EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo structure was decoded but was not successfully interpreted, the password may be incorrect.* . Using the certificate with .pfx and same key file, we are having success. Also, we are seeing the issue in our production environment only.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Net5.0 on IIS is not working, however running locally it works fine. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

By default, an attempt is made to store the certificate in the user certificate store. Of course, this only works if the user profile is available.

More Info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840825/cryptographicexception-was-unhandled-system-cannot-find-the-specified-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149132/what-exactly-happens-when-i-set-loaduserprofile-of-iis-pool)

To Load the Userprofile for an Application pool in IIS follow these steps (copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27242467/7131186)):

1. Go to IIS Manager
2. Go to the application pool instance
3. Click advanced settings
4. Under Process model, set Load User Profile to true