# System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Import Error: "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Hello StackOverflow community,

I'm encountering an issue with a .NET application where I'm getting an error message stating "The system cannot find the file specified." This error occurs when the application attempts to import a cryptographic key. The stack trace points to System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Import method.

it works when i try this locally, but not when i try to host my code online using IIS.

my code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GenerateToken")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult GenerateToken()
{
    try
    {
        var jwt = GenerateJWTAsync();
        return Ok(jwt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return BadRequest("MEssage:"+ex.Message+Environment.NewLine+"Trace:"+ex.StackTrace);
        throw;
    } 
}



private readonly string _privateKey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----XXXXXXX-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n";

string GenerateJWTAsync()
{
    var mail = "XXX";
    var userName = "XXX";
    var keyid = "XXX";
    var cloudUrl = "XXX";
    var rsa = RSA.Create();
    rsa.ImportFromPem(_privateKey);

var key = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);
var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256);


var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim("jti", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim("sub",  Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim("subType", "user"),
            new Claim("name", userName),
            new Claim("email", mail),
            new Claim("email_verified", "true")
        };
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

var token = tokenHandler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(
    issuer: cloudUrl,
    audience: "XXXXX",
    subject: new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
    notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(-30),
    expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(360),
    signingCredentials: signingCredentials
);
token.Header["kid"] = keyid;

var jwtToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

return jwtToken;
```

}

The specific error and stack trace are as follows:

```
Message: The system cannot find the file specified.
Trace:
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Import(ReadOnlySpan`1 keyBlob, String curveName, CngKeyBlobFormat format, CngProvider provider)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CngPkcs8.ImportPkcs8(ReadOnlySpan`1 keyBlob)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CngPkcs8.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(ReadOnlySpan`1 source, Int32& bytesRead)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(ReadOnlySpan`1 source, Int32& bytesRead)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.PemKeyHelpers.ImportPem(ReadOnlySpan`1 input, FindImportActionFunc callback)
   at project.API.Controllers.ApiController.GenerateJWTAsync() in C:\Users\user\source\repos\Website-Backend\Api\Controllers\ApiController.cs:line 72
   at project.API.Controllers.ApiController.GenerateToken() in C:\Users\user\source\repos\Website-Backend\Api\Controllers\ApiController.cs:line 49
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you read this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840825/cryptographicexception-was-unhandled-system-cannot-find-the-specified-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CryptographicException was unhandled: System cannot find the specified file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840825/cryptographicexception-was-unhandled-system-cannot-find-the-specified-file)