# Certenroll on Azure - Generating self signed certificates

Tags: c#, azure, self-signed, x509certificate2, certenroll

I have built a creation self-signing certificates using **Certenroll** (**CERTENROLLLib**). All works locally but as soon as I **deploy** it to **Azure** I get either:

> Server API error: Message:
>   CertEnroll::CX509Enrollment::_CreateRequest: Access is denied.
>   0x80070005 (WIN32: 5 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED), StackTrace:    at
>   CERTENROLLLib.IX509Enrollment2.CreateRequest(EncodingType Encoding)
>   at
>   Foo.Api.Core.Providers.CertificateProvider.GenerateBase64EncodedPfx(String
>   subjectName, Int32 certificateValidityInYears, String password)    at
>   Foo.Api.Core.Services.CertificateService.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Foo.ServerApi.Services.DocumentSigningService.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Foo.ServerApi.Services.DocumentSigningService.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>   at
>   Foo.ServerApi.Controllers.DocumentController.<>c__DisplayClass10_1.<b__5>d.MoveNext()

if using:

```
var cert = new CX509CertificateRequestCertificate();
            cert.InitializeFromPrivateKey(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextMachine, privateKey, "");
```

or

> Server API error: Message:
>   CertEnroll::CX509CertificateRequestCertificate::InitializeFromPrivateKey:
>   The parameter is incorrect. 0x80070057 (WIN32: 87
>   ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER), StackTrace:    at
>   CERTENROLLLib.IX509CertificateRequestCertificate2.InitializeFromPrivateKey(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext
>   Context, IX509PrivateKey pPrivateKey, String strTemplateName)    at
>   Foo.Api.Core.Providers.CertificateProvider.GenerateBase64EncodedPfx(String
>   subjectName, Int32 certificateValidityInYears, String password)    at
>   Foo.Api.Core.Services.CertificateService.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Foo.ServerApi.Services.DocumentSigningService.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Foo.ServerApi.Services.DocumentSigningService.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>   at
>   Foo.ServerApi.Controllers.DocumentController.<>c__DisplayClass10_1.<b__5>d.MoveNext()

if using:

```
var cert = new CX509CertificateRequestCertificate();
            cert.InitializeFromPrivateKey(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextUser, privateKey, "");
```

Is there any way how to overcome this issue with Certenroll on Azure?

**Edit**: final error that lead me to the correct path.

> Server API error: Message: CertEnroll::CX509PrivateKey::Create: The
>   system cannot find the file specified. 0x80070002 (WIN32: 2
>   ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND), StackTrace:    at
>   CERTENROLLLib.IX509PrivateKey2.Create()    at
>   Foo.Api.Core.Providers.CertificateProvider.GenerateBase64EncodedPfx(String
>   subjectName, Int32 certificateValidityInYears, String password)    at
>   Foo.Api.Core.Services.CertificateService.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Foo.ServerApi.Services.DocumentSigningService.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Foo.ServerApi.Services.DocumentSigningService.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>   at
>   Foo.ServerApi.Controllers.DocumentController.<>c__DisplayClass10_1.<b__5>d.MoveNext()

Comment: Related posts - For on-premise deployement : [CryptographicException was unhandled: System cannot find the specified file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17840825/465053).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. use `X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextUser` in `InitializeFromPrivateKey`
2. when creating private key setting `privateKey.MachineContext = false;`
3. on **Azure** add a new **Application Setting**

> **WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE** = 1

that made it work for me

Comment: For me things did't work even after setting `WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE` to 1 when my app service plan was using `Free` tier. It started to work after I upgraded it to `S1` tier.